# how to change font size of a cell in itext?

Tags: java, android-studio, itext

I am using itextpdf to create my pdf file. I have some word that should be added to the cell of a table. The problem is that I cannot change the font size of the list in the cell of the table? Here is my code

```
        float itmeFontSize= 7f;
        float  headingFontSize =  10f;
        PdfPTable innertable6 = new PdfPTable(3);
        innertable6.setWidths(new int[]{40, 30, 30});
        innertable6.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Amount After Tax (In Words:):  "+ shop_currency+ " "
                + num_to_wordss ,
                FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, headingFontSize, Font.NORMAL, 
       BaseColor.BLACK)));
        cell6.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        innertable6.addCell(cell6);
        cell6.setMinimumHeight(50f);
```

So far everything is fine, my problem is starting with the code below

```
        PdfPTable nested = new PdfPTable(1);
        nested.addCell("Total Amount Before Tax:");
        nested.addCell("Total Amount IGST");
        nested.addCell("Total Amount After Tax");
        nested.addCell("GST on reverse Charge");
        PdfPCell nesthousing = new PdfPCell(nested);
        innertable6.addCell(nesthousing);
```

I want to change the font size of **"Total Amount Before Tax:"** and so all.
please guide me .

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```java
Font yourCustomFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 6)
PdfPTable nested = new PdfPTable(1);
nested.addCell("Total Amount Before Tax:", yourCustomFont);
```

You can use any font-family you'd like and the size.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'addCell(java.lang.String, com.itextpdf.text.Font)

Comment: i got my solution my self 

       
float sumaryFontSize= 8.5f; 
       PdfPTable nested = new PdfPTable(1);
                   PdfPCell nestedcell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Total Amount Before Tax:",
                   FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, sumaryFontSize, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
            nestedcell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            nested.addCell(nestedcell2);